# How to remove flicker from CSS button animation?

Tags: html, css

I'am working on one project, where I have one animated button where it fills itself with color.

Here is HTML code:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Button">
```

Here is CSS code:

```
.button{
    border: 3px solid #1161ee;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgba(17,97,238,0);
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.8s;
    transition: all ease 0.8s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;   
}

.button:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 51px 0 0 0 #1161ee;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;    
}
```

You can see it here in action :-) :

https://jsfiddle.net/m8f1k3sp/

The problem with this code is that while  the button fills itself, it flickers randomly and I don't know why. Maybe I just forgot to add something in CSS, or something else is wrong, I don't know. Thank you for your help! :-)

Comment: I believe you need to set more parameters to your box shadow. Try https://jsfiddle.net/m8f1k3sp/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add 1px to the spread radius, I Don't know why it happens with 0 spread radius could be a browser rendering thing? But adding 1px there will fix the issue

https://jsfiddle.net/m8f1k3sp/6/

CSS

```
.button:hover {
     box-shadow: inset 51px 0 0 1px #1161ee;
     -webkit-perspective: 1000;
     -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;    
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have rectangular box shadow inset (shadow with straight line instead of rounded line) in rounded button? https://jsfiddle.net/m8f1k3sp/8/

Comment: @Danedesta the rounded corner comes from your border radius on the button, anyway that's a different question and I am unsure if that can be fixed. You could ask a different question on specifically that

Comment: @Danedesta actually you can fake it like https://jsfiddle.net/m8f1k3sp/9/ border radius on containing element

Answer (score 2):

Here you can try this fiddle.

It's an example. it is not similar to your code.

it may helps you.

```css
.btn {
    border: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 25px 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 700;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.btn {
    border: 3px solid red;
    color: red;
}
.btn:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
.btn::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.btn:after {
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: red;
}
.btn:hover:after, .btn:active:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn">Button</button>
```